# not getting scrollable tabpanel Extjs 4.x with vbox layout

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

Hi I'm trying to get an automatic scrollbar on a tab in tabpanel using a vbox layout.

This is NOT working for me. It's seems that the "height" config value is ignored:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items:  

    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [{
            autoScroll: true,
            height: 1000,
            title: 'Bar',
            layout: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    border: 1,
                    style: {borderColor:'#FF0000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
                    html: 'hi!'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 3,
                    border: 1,
                    style: {borderColor:'#00FF00', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
                    html: 'hi too!'
                }
            ]
        }]
    }        


}).show();
```

Instead, this is WORKING perfectly:

```
function getLongText(rc) {
    var lt = '';
    for(var i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        lt += rc + '<br>';
    }
    return  lt += 'END<br>';
}

Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items:  

    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [{
            autoScroll: true,
            title: 'Bar',
            html: getLongText('A')
        }]
    }        


}).show();
```

The tabpanel is cointained in a 'fit' layout and that should be ok.  I'm also intentionally setting the inner panel height to be greater than that of the container. I took care of specifying  the  'autoscroll'  hint in the inner panel, and that should be ok too.

Apparently I might have a problem with "height" on the inner panel. It doesn't seem to have any effect. Vbox layout is supposed to partition the container height according to the "flex" property of each contained component.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Andrea

Comment: @kevhender You're correct about the align property of the layout, I realized immediately my mistake. You say: **However, that won't achieve what you are looking for, since that just makes the panels stretch to use the full visible height.** and that's what puzzle me: I set the height of the tab to 1000 and I was expecting it to be the base of the computation for the vbox layout.  here's what I'd like to achieve, but I'd like to specify heights proportionally not in pixels: jsfiddle --> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreik65/vFXL5/6/) <--

Comment: ok, thanks to "chamacs" the solution is here [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?266184-not-getting-scrollbars-in-tabpanel-with-vbox-layout&p=975451&viewfull=1#post975451). Thanks anyhow to anyone has tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using `align` incorrectly.  It should be a part of the layout, not the panel.

Instead of this:

```
layout: 'vbox',
align: 'stretch',
```

Use this:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
```

However, that won't achieve what you are looking for, since that just makes the panels stretch to use the full visible height.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, since your second "solution" works.  If you remove the vbox layout and add content, the panels should stretch them and give you the scroll bars that you are looking for:

```
function getLongText(rc) {
    var lt = '';
    for(var i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        lt += rc + '<br>';
    }
    return  lt += 'END<br>';
}
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [{
            autoScroll: true,
            height: 1000,
            title: 'Bar',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    border: 1,
                    style: {borderColor:'#FF0000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
                    html: getLongText('hi!')
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 3,
                    border: 1,
                    style: {borderColor:'#00FF00', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
                    html: getLongText('hi too!')
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}).show();
```

What exactly are you trying to do with a vbox that makes this solution not viable?

Answer (score 0):

In a fit layout the parent container will determine the height of the child as the child "fits" inside the parent container. In your case the height of the tabpanel will be calculated based on the height allocated by the window container.

**EDIT**: (responding to your comment)

According to the docs tabs in the `tabpanel` are layed out with Card layout.

> This layout manages multiple child Components, each **fitted** to the
>   Container ...

I read this to mean that it handles individual tabs similar to the Fit layout where the height is calculated based on available space. I may be wrong about this but that's what it means to me.

There is however a config property on the Card layout that you may want to explore: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card-cfg-manageOverflow

Comment: Correct, that's what I expected. In my test case the 'tabpanel' correctly  fits the container, BUT what I wanted to achieve is to have a taller "tab" in the  containing tabpanel, with auto scroll. Please note that I set  "height: 1000" on the "tab", not the tabset.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a listener on resize event to get the vertical scroll as for Vbox we have to provide height to get scroll but when window size get change scroller height remain constant.

```
Ext.define('DataConfigurations', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px;',
listeners: {
    resize: {
        fn: function(el) {
            this.setHeight(this.up('window').getHeight()-150);  // 150  is extra for my panel coz of headers so have minus it.
            console.log("new height = " +   this.up('window').getHeight()-150);
        }
    }
},
title: "Update Data Configurations",
```

Hopes this help.